# Spring data JPA native query return 1 entity, not a List

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have query (always return List has 1 `SysAutoId`)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SYSAutoID WHERE RefTypeCategory = ?1 AND BranchID = ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
List<SysAutoId> findSpecific(Integer refTypeCategory, Integer branchId);
```

I want create a method like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SYSAutoID WHERE RefTypeCategory = ?1 AND BranchID = ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
SysAutoId findSpecific(Integer refTypeCategory, Integer branchId);
```

return one entity, how to do that?

Comment: If you are using Sping Data JPA, you can get your queries autogenerted by Spring. See the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories).

Answer (score 5):

The return type should be `Optional` of Entity because it only returns the first matching record, look at the syntax of [findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) method

```
Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey)
```

**Code**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SYSAutoID WHERE RefTypeCategory = ?1 AND BranchID = ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<SysAutoId> findSpecific(Integer refTypeCategory, Integer branchId);
```